# How do I pass in an Enum as a parameter such that it can be used to perform a cast?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

In the stub below how do I pass in (MyEnum) as a parameter such that I can use this procedure with any enum?

```
public static Enum Proc(this Enum e)
{
Int32 i = (Int32)(MyEnum)e;
...
```

Here is the solution I have come up with that works:

```
public static Enum Next(this Enum e, Type eT)
{
  Int32 i = (Int32)(Object)e;   
  return (Enum)Enum.Parse(eT, Enum.GetName(eT, Enum.GetName(eT, ++i) == null? i = 0 : i));  
}
```

This solution isn't ideal because I have to do this to get the next value:

```
MyEnum e = (MyEnum)e.Next(typeof(MyEnum));
```

I'd rather just do

```
MyEnum e = e.Next(typeof(MyEnum));
```

Or even better:

```
MyEnum e = e.Next();
```

Anyone who can provide the simple solution can have the point.

Also the code I've written above runs fine in LinqPad but only compiles in WP7 and then throws an exception when I run it (InvalidProgramException).

Comment: *Any* enum? What should happen if the base type for your enum is a `long`? Do you want the values to be truncated?!

Comment: Hi Mark, I don't have any longs to worry about, thanks for the consideration

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Just find the simplest, fewest lines of code way to step through an enum.

Comment: Do you actually want to enumerate all possible values, or just find the successor for any given value?

Comment: just find the next value and when on the last value return the first (i.e. a loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will cycle through the values of any `enum`:

```
static public Enum Cycle(this Enum e)
{
    bool found = false;
    Enum first = null;
    foreach (Enum i in Enum.GetValues(e.GetType()))
    {
        if (first == null)
            first = i;
        if (found)
            return i;
        found = e.Equals(i);
    }
    if (found)
        return first;
    return null;
}
```

For versions of C# that don't have `Enum.GetValues`, you'll have to use a method like this which only works for enums whose values start at 0 and increment by 1:

```
static public Enum Cycle(this Enum e)
{
    var i = ((IConvertible)e).ToInt64(null) + 1;
    var eT = e.GetType();
    var next = Enum.GetName(eT, i);
    return (Enum)Enum.Parse(eT, next ?? Enum.GetName(eT, 0), false);
}
```

Use it like:

```
var nextEnum = (MyEnum)curEnum.Cycle();
```

Comment: @descf: I just put it in my SL app and it compiled just fine. What version are you using?

Comment: Actually I should have put Windows Phone.  In which case you don't deserve the -1.  But I suspect I need you to make some meaningless edit to your post before I can remove it.  Sorry.

Comment: I feel your pain. Maybe the second version will work for you?

Comment: It works fine but I haven't quite got my head around what the line 'var i = ((IConvertible)e).ToInt64(null) + 1;' is doing.

Comment: The `IConvertible` interface has a `ToInt64` (to convert an object to a `long`) method, and `Enum` implements `IConvertible` explicitly, so I cast `e` to an `IConvertible` and call `ToInt64` on it. The `ToInt64` method takes a formatting object, but since we're not passing in a string, that can be `null`. Then I add 1 to increment the value.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I updated this to return the next enum in the list, strongly typed, regardless of what the numbering of the enum values may be.  I'm able to compile and run this under .NET 4 and haven't tried it on WP7, but I don't think I'm using anything that's missing/disabled in SL/WP7.

```
public static T Next<T>(this T e) where T : struct
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    if (!t.IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(t, e)) throw new ArgumentException();
    var intValue = (int)t.GetField(e.ToString()).GetValue(null);
    var enumValues = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Select(x => x.GetValue(null));
    var next = (T?)enumValues.Where(x => (int)x > intValue).Min();
    if (next.HasValue)
        return next.Value;
    else
        return (T)enumValues.Min();
}
```

It can be used as simply as:

```
var nextE = e.Next();
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought this worked initially but it doesn't (It compiled and I still had my own ungeneric method uncommented).  I'm guilty of not having sone my testing properly this time!

Comment: The type 'System.Enum' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Extensions.Proc<T>(T)'

Comment: How are you trying to use the method?  I was expecting something like `MyEnum.SomeValue.Proc()` (equivalently: `ExtensionsClass.Proc<MyEnum>(MyEnum.SomeValue)`), which means `T` is `MyEnum`.

Comment: I think you solved the problem of how to get the integer of the enumeration value but if I try and use T in a procedure it throws the error above.  But then again, I suppose you have solved the bit of the problem I as I have illustrated in my example.  I'll post the solution I have come up with as part of question for you to see.